# reading a column from text using python

Tags: python

```
EXPERIMENT : KSAS1201 SG CLIMAT CHANGE
DATA PATH : C:\DSSAT45\Sorghum\
TREATMENT 1 : N.American SGCER045

@     VARIABLE                              SIMULATED     MEASURED
  --------                                 -------     --------
  Panicle Initiation day (dap)                   62          -99
  Anthesis day (dap)                            115          -99
  Physiological maturity day (dap)              160          -99
  Yield at harvest maturity (kg [dm]/ha)       8478          -99
  Number at maturity (no/m2)                  32377          -99
  Unit wt at maturity (g [dm]/unit)           .0262          -99
```

Hi i have text file like above. I wish to know how to read only column ( like whole colum below simulated and Measured one by one) if possible i also like to know how to import these column in Excel file using python.

Comment: Take a look at the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to read the columns into lists (assuming that the header is always 6 lines):

```
simulated = []
measured = []

with open('input.file') as f:
    for l in f.readlines()[6:]:
        l = l.split()
        simulated.append(l[-2])
        measured.append(l[-1])

print simulated
print measured
```

gives:

```
['62', '115', '160', '8478', '32377', '.0262']
['-99', '-99', '-99', '-99', '-99', '-99']
```

Note that the lists still contain the string representation of the numbers. Parse to numbers with:

```
simulated.append(float(l[-2]))
measured.append(int(l[-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Theodros has given a good answer for reading the file.  To get it into excel, you can either save it as csv (using the `csv` module), or you can try the `xlwt` module (available from PyPi).

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import islice

with open('some.file') as fin:
    for line in islice(fin, 6, None):
        desc, simulated, measured = ' '.join(line.split()).rsplit(' ', 2)
        # do any necessary conversions
```

Then look at `xlwt`/`csv` or XML or whatever so it can be read back into something else...